# Tracking multiple fingers in UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uitouch

I wish to track the location of multiple fingers at once.
The problem is the following: using `touchesMoved` etc. will only supply the touches that moved/ended/began. Existing touches, that haven't been moved at that moment, will be ignored.

What is the best way to track a touch? Is there an id for each touch that let's me recognize it from previous touch events?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` to achieve what you're looking for. Basically, what you do is assume that they are still touching the screen from `touchesBegan` until `touchesEnded` is called (or `touchesCancelled`). `touchesMoved` is used to determine where they move their fingers in that time.

Comment: My issue is that 'touchesMoved' only informs about the touches, that have actually moved. Not the ones that were still touching but didn't move.

Comment: @Marmelador As I explained, you can assume that until `touchesEnded` is called, those touches are in the spot where they last moved. So, you assume the ones that aren't in `touchesMoved` have remained in their last position, which you can save.